# How to make PHP recognize locally installed Python module for executing Python script

Tags: php, python, html, apache, web-services

I have the following Python code, which later will be called using PHP later:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
"""Code name: test.py"""
import BeautifulSoup

import sys
myargs = sys.argv[1]

mylist = ["foo bar qux", "uix nan col"]
for chunk in mylist:
    mems = chunk.split()
    mems.append(myargs)
    print mems
```

And the module BeautifulSoup is installed locally here:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/pdubois/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Now this is the PHP code that calls it

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>MYCODE</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <BR>

     <?php echo '<p>This is the output of my code:</p>'; ?>
     <?php
         exec(`python /misc/path_to_mycode/test.py param1`,$output);
        var_dump($output)
     ?>

   </BODY>
   </HTML>
```

The `index.php` code above resides at `/var/www/html`.

The result I get is this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(34) "Traceback (most recent call last):" 
[1]=> string(65) " File "/u21/pdubois/my_project/test.py", line 15, in " 
[2]=> string(24) " import BeautifulSoup" 
[3]=> string(42) "ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup" }
```

When I comment out `import BeautifulSoup` in test.py. The PHP code returns the correct expected result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(31) "['foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'mcpip1']" 
[1]=> string(31) "['uix', 'nan', 'col', 'mcpip1']" }
```

The question is what should I do to make PHP/Python/Apache recognize the BeautifulSoup or any locally installed modules?

Comment: eval() executes PHP code; you might want [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead

Comment: @MarkBaker: The error is caused by `exec()` not `eval()`. Thanks for pointing it out. I made a mistake while making the OP. I have updated my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you show for BeautifulSoup appears to in your home dir. But I doubt that Apache is running as you: most likely it is running as `www`. So you'd need to install the module for that user, or globally.

Of course, a much better approach would be to stick to one language: if you want to run Python, then write the website using a Python framework; alternatively use a PHP HTML parser.

Comment: 1. I'm not super user and I want PHP to flexibly access  other python modules installed locally, 2. BeautifulSoup is just an example. Actually I'm using many other locally installed Python modules.